# How to exit full-screen mode in Expression Blend

Tags: expression-blend

Somehow, Expression Blend has entered full-screen mode (no window chrome), but I can still minimize/maximize/restore/move through the taskbar button.  I don't see any menu options for full-screen mode, and the normal keyboard shortcuts don't work (F11, Alt-Enter).

I'm not sure how this happened, but I would sorely love to get my chrome back to make interacting with the window easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not even trying to use Blend for my application for a really long time, it turns out it was my own fault to begin with.  I had created a custom chrome control that would find its parent Window and remove the frame.  I wasn't checking design mode, so whenever my control was instantiated by blend, it would remove all the chrome from the window :).

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a Full-screen mode in Blend. Maybe you accidentally hit Tab or F4 and did an Auto-hide to all of the panels?

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't ever seen it before either.  The window chrome is gone, but the panels are there.  I just can't resize / move the window with the mouse.  The system menu works with the keyboard still, but it is VERY annoying.

Answer (score 0):

you can press ESC button

in code use:

```
Application.Current.Host.Content.IsFullScreen = false;
```

[check this](http://www.kirupa.com/blend_silverlight/fullscreen.htm)

Comment: If this were a custom Silverlight app, that would work great.  Unfortunately, Expression Blend itself has gone nuts on me :(.